# How can I randomly execute code 33% of the time in PHP?

Tags: php, random

I'm not so sure how to write this: I want to generate a random number from 0 to 2, then write an `if` statement which executes specific code only 33% of the time.

This is what I tried to do:

```
if (rand(0, 3)=="2") { echo "Success" };
```

Comment: You would have to do `rand(0,2)` to make it 33% chance. `rand(0,3)` gives 25%.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two arguments represent the minimum and maximum random values. If you want a 1-in-3 chance, you should only allow 3 possibilities. Going from minimum 0 to maximum 3 allows 4 possible values (0,1,2,3), so that won't quite do what you want. Also, [`mt_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) is a better function to use than `rand()`.

So it'd be:

```
if (mt_rand(1, 3) == 2)
    echo "Success";
```

Comment: For this purpose the difference between `rand()` and `mt_rand()` will very likely be unnoticeable ;-)

Answer (score 3):

PHP's `rand()` limits are inclusive, so you'd want `if(rand(0,2) == 2)`.

Answer (score 2):

> which executes specific code only 33%
>   of the time.

Just want to point out that using random will only give the code a 33% **chance** of executing as opposed to running it 1/3 of the time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will execute 25% of the time. {0 1 2 3} is a set of 4 numbers. you want to do

`if(rand(1,3)==2)...`

Answer (score 1):

Replace with

```
if (rand(0, 2)==2) { echo "Success"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but I'd do

```
if(!rand(0,2))
 {
   //do stuff
 }
```

for any fraction `1/x` desired, replace `0,2` with `0,x-1`